# How do I get the matched outputs from "^pearl(pig|hog)+$"?

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I get the matched outputs from `^pearl(pig|hog)+$`?

```
var test1 = "pearlhogpigpighog";    // this string should match
var test2 = "pigpighogpearlpig";    // this string shouldn't match
var regex1 = /^pearl(pig|hog)+$/;   // thought this should work
var regex2 = /(pig|hog)/g;          // gives correct output on test1 but accepts test2
test1.match( regex1 );              // output: pearlhogpigpighog,hog
test2.match( regex1 );              // output: null
test1.match( regex2 );              // output: hog,pig,pig,hog
test2.match( regex2 );              // output: pig,pig,hog,pig
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9mz23/5/

What I want is `hog,pig,pig,hog` for `test1` and `null` for test2.

Comment: Why shouldn't `regex1` match `test2`? It contains `perlpig` at the end. if you only want to match at the beginning, you should use the `^` anchor.

Comment: So what's the question now?

Comment: @Barmar: I have now edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript has Neither `\G` CaptureCollection

**A. Test 1**

If I understand, in a string that starts with `pearl`, you want to retrieve individual instances of `hog` or `pig`. First let's discuss general solutions.

**The Roll Royce: CaptureCollection**

In .NET, if you used `pearl(pig|hog)+` against `pearlhogpigpighog`, you could retrieve the values `hog,pig,pig,hog` from the Group 1 Capture Collection. .NET is unique in allowing you to recycle a numbered group. See [Capture Group Numbering & Naming: The Gory Details](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html)

**The Jeep: `\G`**

In engines that support `\G`, you could use `(?:pearl|\G(?<!^))(pig|hog)` to match multiple times and get `hog,pig,pig,hog` from the Group 1 values.

**JavaScript: Two Steps (validate, then process)**

JS has neither of these two features. I would process in two steps:

- Validate the string with `^pearl(pig|hog)+$`
- Retrieve individual matches from Group 1 by processing it with `pig|hog`

---

**B. Test 2**

If I understand, what you want is to match a string that is only constituted of `pig` or `hog`, matching them one at a time. In an engine that supports `\G`, you could do:

```
(?:^(?=(?:pig|hog)+$)|\G(?<!^))(pig|hog)
```

Again, not supporter in in JS. I would proceed in two steps:

- Validate by matching `^(pig|hog)+$`
- Retrieve each match with `(pig|hog)`

---

**Reference**

- [Capture Group Numbering & Naming: The Gory Details](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html)
- [Backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html)

Comment: Two part solution works: http://jsfiddle.net/9mz23/7/ but is there an easier way?

Comment: FYI, greatly expanded answer. Easier way? XRegExp (alternate JS regex library) might support `\G`

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by doing

```
var test1 = 'pearlhogpigpighog';

var groupedMatches = test1.match(/^pearl((?:pig|hog)+)$/);

if (groupedMatches) {
    console.log(groupedMatches[1].match(/pig|hog/g));
}
```

like @zx81 said, you cant accomplish this in one regexp currently.